# Tizen - Get PHP output via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, tizen

I am new to the Tizen SDK. I am an owner of a Gear S2 and want to play a bit around.

I have a raspberry pi which hosts a web server. On this web server, there is a PHP file which outputs "test":
The Php-file simply contains:

```
echo "test";
```

Now I want to show this text on the Gear S2 via Javascript. Is it possible to get the output of the PHP file which lays here:
raspberrypi/test.php
?

I found code like this, but nothing happens with this code:

```
   $.getJSON('http://raspberrypi/test.php', function(e) 
   {
        var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');
        contentText.innerHTML = e.result;
   });
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your web server accessible from S2 via http?

Comment: Both are in the same network. I use multiple PHP scripts from this raspberry in other Android Apps. I just read about permissions which i have to set. But even with the permission "internet" it does not work

Comment: `"test"` isn't in JSON format. Since you're using `getJSON`, try outputting a JSON formatted text with your PHP file.

Comment: getJSON expects valid JSON as the return value, probably... Which `test` is not. Try `echo "true"` to see if that changes anything. Also read up on CORS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing, which are probably the permissions you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will read it now. Also the "echo 'true'" does not work

Answer (score 4):

use get instead of getJSON

```js
   $.get('http://raspberrypi/test.php', function(e) 
   {
        var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');
        contentText.innerHTML = e.result;
   });
```

getJSON - Loads JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

get - any format of response it can get, you echoing a string "test" , it is not JSON format